# Custom Deck class with dynamic memory - core dumped error

Tags: c++

The following code gives me the following error. I don't get this. Please, help.

> *** Error in `./a.out': munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000000400870 *** Aborted (core dumped)

```
template <class T>
class Deck {
private:
  T* arr; // array                                                              
  int n;  // size                                                               
  int rearcursor; // current pos of rear el                                     
  int frontcursor; //...                                                        
public:
  Deck(int sz = 10);
  ~Deck();
  int size();

  T& getFront();
  T& getRear();

  void removeFront();
  void removeRear();

  void addFront(const T& elem);
  void addRear(const T& elem);

  bool empty();
};

template <class T> Deck<T>::Deck(int sz) {
  n = 0;
  T* arr = new T[sz];
  frontcursor = rearcursor = 0;
}

template <class T> Deck<T>::~Deck() {
  delete[] arr;
}

int main()
{
  Deck<int> j(10);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is in this line

```
T* arr = new T[sz];
```

This is declaring a local variable in your constructor that is hiding your member variable `arr`. This means that your member variable `arr` is uninitialized, leadeding to problems when you try to use it or `delete` it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in destructor. I tried to remove uninitialized array, as far as I understood. Nevertheless, I fixed it.